# Running flat file SSIS package via .Net throws "To run a ssis package outside of sql server....install integration services"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to run a flatfile SSIS package via .Net code using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime DLL version 14.0.0.0.

Upon executing I get "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard edition of Integration Services or higher"

I have SSIS for Visual studio 2017 installed, along with with SQL server 2017 both have the SSIS extension installed.

There are a number of questions relating to this error when trying to run via the DTExe directly; but haven't found any questions regarding troubleshooting the Dts.Runtime DLL.

I presume that the DLL calls DTExe, but I don't know to tell which DTExe it will call. Using the "wrong" DTExe is the solution to many other questions regarding this error.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're using the managed object model or using the tooling, both are going to check to see whether the SSIS Service is installed on the machine. It is a requirement of licensing to run an SSIS package that the server running the package be a licensed SQL Server instance. So, the application you've written hopefully is targeted for running on a machine that already has a SQL Server server standard license or above.

For development, that runs you about 50 bucks last I checked. For production, we're talking tens to hundreds of thousands of dollars.

For completeness, SQL Server 2005 and 2008 SSIS packages would run on machines that had the data tooling installed (then called the Business Intelligence Design Studio, or BIDS) because the only way to acquire the installation media was to have the ISO images of SQL Server, Developer edition or above.

With 2012, you could now download the SQL Server Data Tools, SSDT without having the SQL Server product but you lost the ability to run packages outside of the Visual Studio debugger - which is a shame as the debugger can severely impact the throughput of a package.

If you check the licensing requirements - scaling out SSIS to different machines is not included in the Enterprise edition license.

SQL Server does not need SSDT installed to run an SSIS package. The option for installing the tools to run and interactive with it (dtutil, dtexec, ssisdeploymentwizard) .. might exist or not depending on version. But that's *running* packages. Development is where SSDT comes into play. SSDT designs and runs packages within the context of development (Visual Studio debugger). Anything else is going to get blocked by that licensing check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have SQL server enterprise edition. SSDT is downloaded and installed on my development machine's SQL Server client. Is there a requirement for the server hosting the database have SSDT installed as well? I believe it is either way, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Right, but if you check the licensing requirements - scaling out SSIS to different machines is not included in the Enterprise edition license.

Comment: SQL Server does not need SSDT installed to run an SSIS package. The option for installing the tools to run and interactive with it (dtutil, dtexec, ssisdeploymentwizard) .. might exist or not depending on version. But that's running packages. Development is where SSDT comes into play. SSDT designs and runs packages within the context of development (Visual Studio debugger). Anything else is going to get blocked by that licensing check.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm going to try running the app on the server itself. Thanks.